# Neo4J use WHERE on MAX Parameter

Tags: neo4j, cypher

my graph has nodes "T" that can have one or more nodes "TV" assigned. Those nodes "TV" differ in a parameter "version" which can be an integer starting with 0 counting upwards and they also have another parameter called "flag".

I want to find all nodes "T" with the corresponding node "TV" that has "flag = 2". If there is a "flag = 2" I want exactly this node "TV" even if there are higher "version" parameters in other related nodes "TV" than the one with "flag = 2". If there is no "flag = 2" I want the node "TV" with highest (latest) "version" of all existing "TV"-nodes to that node "T".

I tried several ideas and hoped to catch it with "max" but that didn't work out:

```
MATCH (tv:TV) -- (t:T)
WITH max(tv.version) as max
MATCH (tv:TV) -- (t:T) WHERE tv.version = max OR tv.flag = 2
RETURN t, tv
```

Any hints on how to design the query?
Thanks

******* ADD *******
For Jose Bacoy:

I have rewritten and renamed the nodes for better understanding the statement as:

```
match (t:Transaction)--(v:transactionVersion)  
WHERE t.uuid ="61263a4d3c7cb" 
WITH max(v.versionNumber) as max
match (t:Transaction)--(v:transactionVersion)  
WHERE t.uuid ="61263a4d3c7cb" 
RETURN
CASE 
    WHEN v.versionFlag = 2 THEN v.uuid
    WHEN v.versionNumber = max THEN v.uuid
END AS versionUUID
```

The result is that I become two nodes, the one that may have a versionFlag = 2 and the one with the max versionNumber.
But I want something like a break: If Neo4J finds a versionFlag = 2 it shall return the corresponding node only and drop the rest. If it does not find a versionFlag = 2 I want to get only the node with the highest versionNumber. So its a kind of either or with only one result instead now two.

Comment: I tried your query using my own test data and it works. Please share your own test data and I will check. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The max() aggregation isn't enough, we need another aggregation here at the same time to determine if there are any rows where `versionFlag = 2`, since that will changeup the comparison you want to make later.

```
match (t:Transaction)--(v:transactionVersion)  
WHERE t.uuid ="61263a4d3c7cb" 
WITH max(v.versionNumber) as max, max(CASE WHEN v.versionFlag = 2 THEN 2 ELSE 0 END) as flag
WITH max, flag = 2 as useFlag
match (t:Transaction)--(v:transactionVersion)  
WHERE t.uuid ="61263a4d3c7cb" AND ((useFlag AND v.versionFlag = 2) OR (NOT useFlag AND v.versionNumber = max))
RETURN v.uuid AS versionUUID
```